# how to use _.cloneWith to transform an object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to transform an object like `{a: 123, b: '234'}` to `{a: '123', b: '234'}`, so I try code:

```
var m = {a:123,b:'234'};
var n = _.cloneWith(m, v => {
  if (typeof v === number) return v + '';
});
```

But I got `n` just to be a string `[object Object]`. `_.cloneWith` send the whole `m` to the customizer.

But I can not use `_.cloneDeepWith` beacuse I have different transform logic on different level. Say I want to transform `x` to `y`:

```
var x = {
  a: 123,
  b: '234',
  c: { c0: '345', c1: 456 },
}
// transform x to y
var y = {
  a: '123',
  b: '234',
  c: { c0: 345, c1: 456 },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_. cloneDeepWith()` customizer is called with the `(value [, index|key, object, stack])`, so you can use the `key` to supply a different clone function.

In this case, I call `_.cloneDeepWith()`, but with a different logic:

```js
const cloneC = obj => _.cloneDeepWith(obj, v => 
  _.isString(v) && _.isNumber(+v) ? Number(v) : undefined
);

const clone = obj => _.cloneDeepWith(obj, (v, k) => {
  if(_.isNumber(v)) return String(v);
  
  if(k === 'c') return cloneC(v);
});

const m = {"a":123,"b":"234"};
const x = {"a":123,"b":"234","c":{"c0":"345","c1":456}};

console.log(clone(m));
console.log(clone(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```